# asp.net Cyrillic/Latin characters input validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I ve got validation/maybe mask on the input issue.

What is the best way to let user type in only latin or cyrillic characters into input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  regex [\p{IsCyrillic}] and \p{L}